# Android Strange Issue with GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview, android-adapter

Ok so i'm trying to use a grid view, 4 columns, with a custom adapter. I'm getting two very strange issues

Issue #1: very strange, when it loads, row 1 column 1 is blank. Then when I start scrolling down, the first column in the first row that becomes visible is blank. But when I scroll back to the top those blank views show up.

Issue #2: Once I begin scrolling, if I fling fast to the top, the grid goes beyond its bounds, once it scrolls up to the point where I see nothing, I can't scroll at all and the gridView is lost or completely invisible.

I'm targeting API 21 so this is on my Lolipop device but I've tested this on kitkat 4.4.2 and get the exact same behavior.

Here is my GridView layout/initialization
activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity, initializing gridview

```
        ArrayList<AppDetail> appList = getInstalledApps();

        AppGridAdapter adapter = new AppGridAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, appList);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AppGridAdapter.java (imports removed)

```
public class AppGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> {

    public AppGridAdapter(Context context, int rid, List<AppDetail> list) {
        super(context, rid, list);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_grid_item, parent, false);

            // set width/height = 1/4 parent width
            int len = parent.getWidth() / 4;
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = (AbsListView.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = len;
            params.height = len;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgAppIcon);
            holder.tvLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvAppLabel);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        AppDetail app = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(app.icon);
        holder.tvLabel.setText(app.label);

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView tvLabel;
    }
}
```

So as you can see code is very simple and straight forward. This is the format i've always used for my custom adapters. I have no clue whats wrong with it.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger (or logging) and ensuring that `parent.getWidth()` is not zero? Seems like that may be the only possible issue. Possibly that is being called too early when fetching the first view.

Comment: Well I assumed since the child is suppose to inflate at that point the parent is already inflated. But all the other items except for the few described show up correctly.

Comment: Never mind you seemed to be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

BTellez was right. The issue was in changing the view bounds when inflating. Just removed that block and it works now.